# Filter results by customising the taxonomy query in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom loop which is working perfect, the loop is able to filter posts by custom fields.

My goal is to be able to filter the taxonomy results by a custom field.

I now need to create a taxonomy template which also uses these filters and I'm stuck! How can I inject the custom query variables into the native taxonomy query? this is my custom query.

```
<?php

  $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'acapella',
        'posts_per_page' => 18,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => $order,
        'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'OR',
                               array('key' => 'studio_acapella',
                                        'value' => $yes,
                                        'compare' => '='
                                    ),

                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'studio_acapella',
                                        'value' => $no,
                                        'compare' => '='
                                    )
                                )
                            )); 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
```

Comment: Have a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: try this http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/